# Android: customsearchadapter displays empty results

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to get my custom search box suggestions to display, but the results I receive are empty. I followed a few guides to implement this feature, namely:

- For the contentprovidor: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-iv-android-content-providers/
- To make it work in ABS: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/pull/653/files

This resulted in this code:

Adding the search box:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.building_search, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new BuildingSuggestionsAdapter(this, searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()), searchView));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Adding the buildings to my database:

```
for (Resto resto : restos) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TableBuildings.Buildings.NAME, resto.name);
    values.put(TableBuildings.Buildings.DISTANCE, "3");
    getContentResolver().insert(TableBuildings.Buildings.CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

The BuildingSuggestionAdapter:

```
public class BuildingSuggestionsAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private static final int QUERY_LIMIT = 50;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private SearchableInfo searchable;

    public BuildingSuggestionsAdapter(Context context, SearchableInfo info, SearchView searchView) {
        super(context, null, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        this.searchable = info;
        this.searchView = searchView;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TableBuildings.Buildings.NAME));
        TextView namet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.resto_search_name);
        namet.setText(name);

        String man = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TableBuildings.Buildings.DISTANCE));
        TextView manuf = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.resto_search_distance);
        manuf.setText(man);

        Toast.makeText(context, name + " " + man, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        return this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.resto_search_suggestion_view, null);
    }

    /**
     * Use the search suggestions provider to obtain a live cursor. This will be called in a worker
     * thread, so it's OK if the query is slow (e.g. round trip for suggestions). The results will
     * be processed in the UI thread and changeCursor() will be called.
     */
    @Override
    public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
        String query = (constraint == null) ? "" : constraint.toString();
        /**
         * for in app search we show the progress spinner until the cursor is returned with the
         * results.
         */
        Cursor cursor = null;
        if (searchView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE
            || searchView.getWindowVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            cursor = getSuggestions(searchable, query, QUERY_LIMIT);
            // trigger fill window so the spinner stays up until the results are copied over and
            // closer to being ready
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.getCount();
                return cursor;
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        }
        // If cursor is null or an exception was thrown, stop the spinner and return null.
        // changeCursor doesn't get called if cursor is null
        return null;
    }


    public Cursor getSuggestions(SearchableInfo searchable, String query, int limit) {

        if (searchable == null) {
            return null;
        }

        String authority = searchable.getSuggestAuthority();
        if (authority == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Uri.Builder uriBuilder = new Uri.Builder()
            .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)
            .authority(authority)
            .query("")
            .fragment("");

        // if content path provided, insert it now
        final String contentPath = searchable.getSuggestPath();
        if (contentPath != null) {
            uriBuilder.appendEncodedPath(contentPath);
        }

        // append standard suggestion query path
        uriBuilder.appendPath(SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY);

        // get the query selection, may be null
        String selection = searchable.getSuggestSelection();
        // inject query, either as selection args or inline
        String[] selArgs = null;
        if (selection != null) {    // use selection if provided
            selArgs = new String[]{query};
        } else {                    // no selection, use REST pattern
            uriBuilder.appendPath(query);
        }

        if (limit > 0) {
            uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("limit", String.valueOf(limit));
        }

        Uri uri = uriBuilder.build();

        // finally, make the query
        return mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, selArgs, null);
    }
}
```

The providor:

```
public class BuildingSuggestionProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Buildings.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Buildings";

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            //create table to store user names
            db.execSQL("Create table " + TABLE_NAME + "( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, DISTANCE TEXT);");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String s, String[] as) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues) {
        // get database to insert records
        sqlDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        // insert record in user table and get the row number of recently inserted record
        long rowId = sqlDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, "", contentvalues);
        if (rowId > 0) {
            Uri rowUri = ContentUris.appendId(TableBuildings.Buildings.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon(), rowId).build();
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(rowUri, null);
            return rowUri;
        }
        throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        return (dbHelper == null) ? false : true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        qb.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, null, null, null, sortOrder);
        c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues, String s, String[] as) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The tablebuildings:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
public class TableBuildings {

    public static final String AUTHORITY = "be.ugent.zeus.hydra.ui.map.suggestions.BuildingSuggestionProvider";

    // BaseColumn contains _id.
    public static final class Buildings implements BaseColumns {

        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://be.ugent.zeus.hydra.ui.map.suggestions.BuildingSuggestionProvider");
        // Table column
        public static final String NAME = "NAME";
        public static final String DISTANCE = "DISTANCE";
    }
}
```

And finally the XML used to define the search box, followed by the xml used for the providor in my application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:label="@string/resto_search_label"
            android:hint="@string/resto_search_hint" 
            android:searchSuggestAuthority="be.ugent.zeus.hydra.ui.map.suggestions.BuildingSuggestionProvider" />



<provider
            android:name=".ui.map.suggestions.BuildingSuggestionProvider"
            android:authorities="be.ugent.zeus.hydra.ui.map.suggestions.BuildingSuggestionProvider" />
```

The results I got where the following:
No errors; it opens up the searchview and queries the contentprovider. The weird part is that the query methods in the Provider gets called, but it doesn't get called from the adapter, as in, when I put a breakpoint, my program doesn't stop.
Visually, my keyboard pops up and I see a list, but the list only contains empty items...

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but I faced the same issue and have solved it with the use of the Constants provided by the *SearchManager* class as column names in my database.
See [a tutorial on search on the Android developers site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html).

The [SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1) is what you need specifically. This is the primary text the ContentProvider needs to show in the resulting ListView and what it will search through.